# Is it possible to mix error types when doing early returns using the `?` operator in Rust?

Tags: rust

The following code

```
fn get_issues(addr: &str) -> Result<(), std::error::Error> {
    let mut result = String::new();
    reqwest::get(&format!("{}/issues", addr))?.read_to_string(&mut result)?;

    unimplemented!();
}
```

yields

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::error::Error + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied                          
  --> src/main.rs:37:1        
   |                          
37 | / fn get_issues(addr: &str) -> Result<(), std::error::Error> {                                                       
38 | |     let mut result = String::new();                   
39 | |     reqwest::get(&format!("{}/issues", addr))?.read_to_string(&mut result)?;                                       
40 | |                        
41 | |     unimplemented!();  
42 | | }                      
   | |_^ `std::error::Error + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time                                
   |                          
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::error::Error + 'static`                            
   = note: required by `std::result::Result`
```

However, `reqwest::get()` returns `Result<.., reqwest::Error>` and `read_to_string()` returns `Result<.., std::io::Error>`. I would like to use some kind of common error type to avoid type errors.

Is there some kind of error type I can use to make `get_issues` work as-is or do I need to convert the errors to my own error type?

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the chapter on [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't feel it really answered my question. But I found an answer in the _Rust proper error handling question..._. Seems like I need to create my own error type. Thanks :-)

Comment: I found the Error handling chapter of the first edition covers this really well: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/error-handling.html#working-with-multiple-error-types